# Replace table row number with the number next to the last table row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am adding rows via onclick button. I have no issues with adding/appending rows to the last table row and deleting each. My problem is, how can I make the row number to be always next to the last?

My code for adding rows:

```
var id_age;
function AddRow() {
    var rowCount = $('#dependent_table tbody tr').length;
        id_age = 'age_dependent_'+ rowCount;
        $("#dependent_table").append( "<tr>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:45%;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name_dependent["+rowCount+"]' id='name_dependent_" + rowCount + "'></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:10%;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='age_dependent["+rowCount+"]' id='"+id_age+"' disabled></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:35%;'><div class='col-md-12'><div class='form-group has-feedback' style='margin-top:12px;'><input class='form-control datePick' id='dob_dependent_"+ i +"' name='dob_dependent["+rowCount+"]' placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD' data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd' type='text' onchange=\"CalculateAge(this.value,'" + id_age + "');\"/><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback'></i></div></div></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:10%;'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btnDelete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>"+ "</tr>");
        rowCount++;
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}

function Delete(){ 
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr 
    par.remove(); 
}
```

Example:

```
<tr id="dep_row_1">
    <td><input type="text" name="name_dependent[1]" value="value1"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="dep_row_2">
    <td><input type="text" name="name_dependent[2]" value="value2"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="dep_row_3">
    <td><input type="text" name="name_dependent[3]" value="value3"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="dep_row_4">
    <td><input type="text" name="name_dependent[4]" value="value4"></td>
</tr>
```

If I delete a row in the middle:

```
<tr id="dep_row_3">
    <td><input type="text" name="name_dependent[3]" value="value3"></td>
</tr>
```

Then the table should now be:

```
<tr id="dep_row_1">
    <td><input type="text" name="name_dependent[1]" value="value1"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="dep_row_2">
    <td><input type="text" name="name_dependent[2]" value="value2"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="dep_row_3">
    <td><input type="text" name="name_dependent[3]" value="value4"></td>
</tr>
```

where **dep_row_4** became **dep_row_3** and so on.

Is this possible?

With my current code, when I have a total of 5 rows and I deleted the 4th row, The id of the last row is still 5 which should be 4.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!
-Eli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is grab the id of the current row, select the subsequent row and iterate through them using jQuery's `nextAll` and perform the updates you need.

**Edit:** Update to include AddRow logic and fixed binding issue

```js
var id_age;
function AddRow() {
    var rowCount = $('#dependent_table tbody tr').length;
        id_age = 'age_dependent_'+ rowCount; 
        $("#dependent_table tbody").append( "<tr id='dep_row_" + rowCount + "'>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:45%;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name_dependent["+rowCount+"]' id='name_dependent_" + rowCount + "'></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:10%;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='age_dependent["+rowCount+"]' id='"+id_age+"' disabled></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:35%;'><div class='col-md-12'><div class='form-group has-feedback' style='margin-top:12px;'><input class='form-control datePick' id='dob_dependent_"+ rowCount +"' name='dob_dependent["+rowCount+"]' placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD' data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd' type='text' onchange=\"CalculateAge(this.value,'" + id_age + "');\"/><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback'></i></div></div></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:10%;'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btnDelete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>"+ "</tr>");
        $("#dep_row_" + rowCount + " .btnDelete").bind("click", Delete); //bind the callback only to the newly created row's delete button
        rowCount++;        
}

function Delete() {
  var rowToDelete = $(this).parent().parent();
  var currentId = parseInt(rowToDelete.attr('id').split('_').pop());
  var nextRow = $('#dep_row_' + (currentId + 1)); //get the next row
  
  rowToDelete.remove(); //remove the current row
  
  if (nextRow) { //if there's another row
    nextRow.attr('id', 'dep_row_' + currentId); //replace the id with the old one
      // go through each input and rename
      $('input', nextRow).each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var inputName = input.attr('name').split('[')[0]; 
        input.attr('name', inputName + '[' + currentId + ']');
      });
    ++currentId;

    //do the same for the subequent rows
    console.dir(nextRow.nextAll());
    nextRow.nextAll().each(function() {
      var row = $(this);
      row.attr('id', 'dep_row_' + currentId);
      $('input', row).each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var inputName = input.attr('name').split('[')[0]; 
        input.attr('name', inputName + '[' + currentId + ']');
      });
      ++currentId;
    });
   }

}

$('#add').on('click', AddRow);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add row</button>
<table id="dependent_table">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm testing this on my code. I will let you know. Thanks @xorspark!

Comment: I modified your code so it would fit mine. It was working fine with deleting one row. But when I added multiple rows and delete one in the middle (I have a total of 7 rows and deleted the 5th row), the rest has the same row number. This is the result:

Comment: @jeepers_creepers This is because you're re-binding the delete callback to all the delete buttons so it repeats itself somehow, overwriting the rest. I updated the example to include a fix for your AddRow logic as well as updated my version of Delete handle the rows generated by your AddRow method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for code that iterates over all of the table rows and updates the name attribute.  You could do this with a function and a `for` loop:

```
function updateNames() {
    var rows = $('#dependent_table tbody tr');
    var numOfRows = rows.length;
    var i;

    for (i=0; i<numOfRows; i++) {
        rows.eq(i).attr('name', 'name_dependent['+(i+1)+']');
    }
}
```

Calling this will iterate and update all your table rows.

Comment: Hi @anied! IT WORKS! But apologies, how can I start with 0 instead of 1?And is it possible to iterate the `<td>`, too? I have 3 `<td>` per `<tr>`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe iterate through rest of rows (after the deleted one) and decrease their numbers by 1?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have made an edit on the question and also included my Delete function. Is it possible even if no refresh is happening?

Comment: Of course. Mateusz has posted you a good answer for this. Attach your code into place where he commented and it will be done nicely.
If you are using JQuery, you can also change onClick function to $(deletebutton).on( "click", function() { })';

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (you will modify each row's attributes starting with 'number' of deleted row):

```
function deleteRow(number) {
    // actions with row delete here ...

    // after delete row
    var counter = 1;
    $('#dependent_table tbody tr').each( function() {
        if(counter >= number) {
             $(this).attr('id', "dep_row_" + number);
             $(this).attr('name', "name_dependent[" + number + ']');
             // etc..
        }
        counter++;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I have made an edit on the question and also included my Delete function. How should I get the 'number'? when I hit the delete button for each row, only that row is being removed and no refresh is happening.

Comment: You can get this 'number' from attributes values for example by left only number from 'id' and convert it into integer:
`var id_value = $(this).attr('id');
var number = parseInt ( id_value.replace("dep_row_", '') );`

Answer (score 0):

Props to @xorspark for providing this precise solution! I have just modified the input id's to be the same with the name attributes and other parts to fit my code. Thanks to @anied, too! Thanks everyone for your help! :)

```js
var id_age;
function AddRow() {
    var rowCount = $('#dependent_table tbody tr').length;
        id_age = 'age_dependent_'+ rowCount; 
        $("#dependent_table tbody").append( "<tr id='dep_row_" + rowCount + "'>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:45%;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name_dependent["+rowCount+"]' id='name_dependent_" + rowCount + "'></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:10%;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='age_dependent["+rowCount+"]' id='"+id_age+"' disabled></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:35%;'><div class='col-md-12'><div class='form-group has-feedback' style='margin-top:12px;'><input class='form-control datePick' id='dob_dependent_"+ rowCount +"' name='dob_dependent["+rowCount+"]' placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD' data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd' type='text' onchange=\"CalculateAge(this.value,'" + id_age + "');\"/><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback'></i></div></div></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:10%;'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btnDelete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>"+ "</tr>");
        $("#dep_row_" + rowCount + " .btnDelete").bind("click", Delete); //bind the callback only to the newly created row's delete button
        rowCount++;        
}

function Delete() {
  var rowToDelete = $(this).parent().parent();
  var currentId = parseInt(rowToDelete.attr('id').split('_').pop());
  var nextRow = $('#dep_row_' + (currentId + 1)); //get the next row
  
  rowToDelete.remove(); //remove the current row
  
  if (nextRow) { //if there's another row
    nextRow.attr('id', 'dep_row_' + currentId); //replace the id with the old one
      $('input', nextRow).each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var inputName = input.attr('name').split('[')[0]; 
        input.attr('name', inputName + '[' + currentId + ']');
      });
    ++currentId;

    //do the same for the subequent rows
    console.dir(nextRow.nextAll());
    nextRow.nextAll().each(function() {
      var row = $(this);
      row.attr('id', 'dep_row_' + currentId);
      $('input', row).each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var inputName = input.attr('name').split('[')[0]; 
        input.attr('name', inputName + '[' + currentId + ']');
      });
      ++currentId;
    });
   }

}

$('#add').on('click', AddRow);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add row</button>
<table id="dependent_table">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```